# How to burn a dual layer dvd iso from the command line

Tags: server, command-line, dvd

How do you burn a DVD-DL iso from the command line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
growisofs -speed=2 -dvd-compat -Z /dev/dvdrw=dvd_image.iso
```

Replace `/dev/dvdrw` with your dvd writer path and `dvd_image.iso` with the iso filename
If you do not have growisofs installed you will need to install the `dvd+rw-tools` package with the following command

```
sudo apt-get install dvd+rw-tools
```